# Altarnative for "new" operator in c++98

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm trying to to use "new" operator to place object with constructor at specific adress and i'm using compiler with C++98 standard.

```
myClass* myObj
myObj = new(&adress) myClass(a, b);
```

Unfortunetally, I've got an error:

"no matching function for call to 'operator new(unsigned int, myClass*)"

How can I achieve the same result without "new" word? Or maybe there is another way to fix it?

Comment: Did you forget `#include <new>`? Placement `new` need it.

Comment: @Blaze it wouldn't work, as a placement `new` is what OP is trying to use.